# combine multiple calls of enotez' printnotes with split option

Tags: koma-script, enotez

Using the enotez-package for a book based on scrbook I want to split the endnotes on a per-chapter base. Therefor I use repetitive calls of `\printendnotes` at the end of each chapter. Since those are many I want to include the sectional header using the split option of the package. The problem is: without the split option the endnotes list **is** cleared after each call of `\printendnotes` - with the split option it is **not**. So for chap 1 I get the notes of chap 1, for chap 2 I get the notes of chap 1 and chap 2 and so on.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[list-name={Anmerkungen},list-heading={}]{enotez}
%
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
{ heading   = \addsec*{#1},
  notes-sep = -0.5\parskip,
  format    = \normalfont\footnotesize\leftskip1.8em,
  number    = \textsuperscript{#1}
}
\setenotez{
  reset = false,
  split = section,
  split-heading = {#1},
  split-title = {\noindent{\bfseries sec <ref>}}
}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{chap 1}
\section{sec 1.1}
This\endnote{or that (1)} is\endnote{might be (1)} a good\endnote{or bad (1)} idea\endnote{right? (1)}

\section{sec 1.2}
This\endnote{or that (2)} is\endnote{might be (2)} a good\endnote{or bad (2)} idea\endnote{right? (2)}

\printendnotes[custom]

\chapter{chap 2}
\section{sec 2.1}
This\endnote{or that (3)} is\endnote{might be (3)} a good\endnote{or bad (3)} idea\endnote{right? (3)}

\section{sec 2.2}
This\endnote{or that (4)} is\endnote{might be (4)} a good\endnote{or bad (4)} idea\endnote{right? (4)}

\printendnotes[custom]
\end{document}
```

I did not find a way to clear the endnotes list - even the enotez package doc did not help me. Sorry if I've overseen something.

UPDATE: the enotez package doc states (page 7):
*"First of all enotez will rely on the fact that you use `\printendnotes` only once! If you call it more times nobody knows what will happen..."*

So this seems to be unsupported... :(

Guess it's time to contact the author of enotez for assistance...

Comment: I think that the comment on page 7 is only referred to the `split` option. Indeed, using `\printendnotes` at the end of each chapter just prints the notes for the chapter.

Comment: @egreg right, but the split option adds the sectional headings to the endnotes list which is what what's wanted here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no real solution but a workaround:

defining a macro to inject manually the section heading to the list and use multiple `\printendnotes` calls **without** the split option (since I can't read expl3 to understand how to clear the list).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enotez}
%
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
  { heading   = \addsec*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#1},
    notes-sep = -0.5\parskip,
    format    = \normalfont\footnotesize\leftskip1.8em,
    number    = \textsuperscript{#1}
  }
\setenotez{
  reset = false
  }
%
%%%%%% code added
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
% list opener
\def\eno@libeg{\enotez_list_postamble: \noindent\group_begin: \tl_use:N \l__enotez_list_format_tl}
% list terminater
\def\eno@liend{\group_end: \enotez_list_postamble: \hspace*{-1.4em}\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4.5ex}}
% call to add inlist heading
\def\addenotezsectionheading#1{
  \int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
    % inject entry, see pg 5 enotez_en.pdf
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\enotez@note{\int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int}
                                       {}
                                       {\int_use:N \g__enotez_list_printed_int}
                                       {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
                                       {\arabic{section}}
                                       {m}
                                       {\noexpand\eno@liend{\noexpand\bfseries #1}\noexpand\eno@libeg}}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother
%%%%%% end code added
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{chap 1}
\section{sec 1.1}\addenotezsectionheading{sec 1.1 (added)}
This\endnote{or that (1)} is\endnote{might be (1)} a good\endnote{or bad (1)} idea\endnote{right? (1)}

\section{sec 1.2}\addenotezsectionheading{sec 1.2 (added)}
This\endnote{or that (2)} is\endnote{might be (2)} a good\endnote{or bad (2)} idea\endnote{right? (2)}

\printendnotes[custom]

\chapter{chap 2}
\section{sec 2.1}\addenotezsectionheading{sec 2.1 (added)}
This\endnote{or that (3)} is\endnote{might be (3)} a good\endnote{or bad (3)} idea\endnote{right? (3)}

\section{sec 2.2}\addenotezsectionheading{sec 2.2 (added)}
This\endnote{or that (4)} is\endnote{might be (4)} a good\endnote{or bad (4)} idea\endnote{right? (4)}

\printendnotes[custom]
\end{document}
```

I know the heading design is hard coded (uncool) but it works...